# PHP Upload CSV to update database records but exclude duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import-from-excel

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. I have a database with around 500 records/rows in MySQL and I need to update it daily. The problem is the file I upload will be Excel file (I probably need to convert it to CSV before upload?). Also I need to only upload records that don't exist yet in the current MySQL Database. The Unique field is named "MemberID".

What is the best way to achieve this? If I insert each rows (so I can check first if the record/row should be inserted to the Database) one by one like using a loop, will that be a slow process for uploading 500 records?

I'm new to PHP from VBA Programming and I only know how to insert records one at a time. Your suggestions is most appreciated.

Comment: INSERT IGNORE INTO... will allow you to run a query with a unique key and ignore any entries that would create a duplicate key. I suggest reading the INSERT syntax in the MYSQL manual. You can insert multiple records at the same time.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @DragonYen I think this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got three options:

1. `REPLACE` (**recommended** as you're using a database that's updated daily - you'll never know, if old records didn't change from last update):

   ```
   REPLACE INTO db_name (id,value) VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)
   ```

   It will affect all rows.
2. `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (that's probably what you've been searching for, it will update whatever you want or simply leave the row 'as is'):

   ```
   INSERT INTO db_name (id,value) VALUES (1,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id
   ```
3. `INSERT IGNORE INTO` (it will update only those rows that're new, skipping duplicates, but if you'll encounter *key violations* MySQL will **NOT** raise an error):

   ```
   INSERT IGNORE INTO db_name (id,value) VALUES (1,1);
   ```

Also, some alternatives: [SQL Merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)).

Comment: Thanks @eeree these will be very helpful. My goal is to ignore the rows that already exist in the MySQL database (Duplicate). I want to keep the old records and upload only the new ones (ones that aren't uploaded yet) :)